# Solución de sub arreglos especiales usando programación dinámica

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando realizar el problema que dejare a continuación, lo he intentado pero no lo he logrado terminar, aunque debe haber una solución usando DP. ¿Alguien podría guiarme? Ya que no he usado esta técnica muchas veces y no se como encararlo.

> Dado un arreglo X de N elementos  donde cada uno de ellos es un entero entre 0 y 9 inclusive, decimos que un sub-arreglo  del mismo es **ESPECIAL** , si su tamaño es igual a la suma de sus elementos.
> Debe calcular cuantos sub arreglos especiales hay en el arreglo.

Las cotas de N, llegan hasta 10^5

Mi código fue realizado utilizando la técnica de vetanas deslizantes, pero no es lo suficientemente eficiente.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector <int> V;

void Separar(string CAD){ 
    
    string N;
    
    for(int i=0;i<CAD.size();i++) { 
        
        N = CAD[i];
        
        V.push_back(stoi(N));
        
    }
    
    
}
    
    int main() {
        
        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);
        
        int k=2,ESPECIALES=0,P=0,N=0; 
        string CAD;
        
        cin>>N;
        cin.ignore();
        cin>>CAD;
        
        Separar(CAD);
        
        //for(int j=0;j<V.size();j++) { cout<<V[j] << " "; }
        
        for(int i=0;i<V.size();i++){
            if(V[i]==1){
                ESPECIALES++;
            }
            P=P+V[i];
        }
        
        if(P==V.size()){ESPECIALES++;}
        
        P=0;
        
        while(k<N){
            
            for(int j=0;j<k;j++) { 
                P = P + V[j];
            }
            
            
            if(P == k){ESPECIALES++;}
            
            for(int j=1;j<=N-k;j++){
                
                P = P - V[j-1];
                P = P + V[j+k-1];
                
                if(P == k){ESPECIALES++;}
                
            }
            
            k++; P=0; 
            
        }
        
        cout<<ESPECIALES<<endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Cualquier documento que puedan compartirme para aprender mas acerca de este tema es bienvenido, gracias desde ya.

Comment: ¿Qué significa que "*su tamaño es igual a la suma de sus elementos*"?

Comment: El tamaño del subarreglo es igual a la suma de sus elementos, por ejemplo, el arreglo _1 0 2_  tiene como sub arreglo especial a _1_ ya que el tamaño de ese subarreglo es 1 y la suma de sus elementos tambien es 1. Lo mismo pasa con _1 0 2_ ya que el subarreglo tiene un tamaño de 3, y la sumatoria de sus elementos es 3

Comment: Sabes cuál es el comportamiento asintótico de la solución? Se me ocurre una con tiempo `O(n^2)` y espacio `O(n)`, la solución que publicaste funciona correctamente? (Me cuesta trabajo seguir la lógica con esos nombres descriptivos de las variables jaja)

Comment: La solución que publique fue testeada con algunos casos de prueba y funcionaron todos, me faltaría mejorar la eficiencia. Que se te ocurre ? Podes hacer algo desde 0, no necesariamente basarte en mi solución.

Comment: Checa tu código para el arreglo `2, 0, 6, 6, 9`. Según creo debería de retornar `1` como respuesta, pues hay un sub arreglo que cumple con la condición. Dicho arreglo es `2, 0` pues su longitud es de `2` y la suma de sus elementos es `2`. Ejecuté el código publicado e imprimió `0`.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Lo revisare. Me gustaría saber tu idea de solución.

Comment: ¿ Que resultados esperas para la secuencia `0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1` ?

Comment: ¿Le encontraste solución al ejercicio?

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurrió la siguiente solución:

Ir de menos a más, calculando la suma de los elementos de un subarreglo. En general, podemos definir una función recursiva que calcule el número de sub arreglos especiales como sigue:

[image: Función recursiva]

Donde `v` es el vector `i` es la posición, `n` es la longitud de `v` y `subarreglosespeciales(v, i)` calcula el número de subarreglos especiales desde `i` hasta `n` del vector `v`.

Evidentemente programar esa solución recursiva sería una pésima idea pues tendría un performance muy pobre. Pero es importante mencionarla ya que me basé en esa idea para llegar a la solución final.

Si es complicado lo que escribí anteriormente, seguro este ejemplo lo descomplica. Imaginemos que tenemos el arreglo `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Podemos generar una matriz como la siguiente

[image: matrix]

Que contiene los posibles subarreglos especiales. Y si te fijas detalladamente, encontrarás los patrones y tendrá mucho más sentido la explicación de arriba. Agrego otras imágenes de ayuda

[image: M]

[image: matrix 2]

Ponerlo como matriz es simplemente para hacerlo visual e intuitivo, pero realmente eso no significa que en el código se tenga que manejar así. De hecho no hay que crear ninguna matriz y los valores se pueden ir calculando *on the fly*, puedes calcular los nuevos valores tomando los valores previamente calculados (para eso es la variable `sums` del código que está abajo).

La implementación es sencilla una vez se entiende el algoritmo

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

std::default_random_engine randomEngine;

std::string vector2String(const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& begin, const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& end) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::copy(begin, end - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss, ", "));

    oss << *(end - 1);
    return oss.str();
}

int mySolution(const std::vector<int>& elements) {
    int n_elements = elements.size();
    int n_special_arrays = 0;

    // this new array will contain the current row for the matrix
    std::vector<int> sums(elements.size());

    // create the first row of the matrix
    sums.at(0) = elements.at(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < n_elements; ++i)
        sums.at(i) = sums.at(i - 1) + elements.at(i);

    // compute the rows remaining
    int expected_array_size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; ++i) {
        if (sums.at(i) == 1) {
            ++n_special_arrays;
            std::cout << "sub array: " << vector2String(elements.begin() + i, elements.begin() + i + 1) << " is SPECIAL because the sum is 1, the same size of the array" << std::endl;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n_elements; ++j) {
            expected_array_size = j - i + 1;

            if (sums.at(j) == expected_array_size) {
                ++n_special_arrays;
                std::cout << "sub array: " << vector2String(elements.begin() + i, elements.begin() + i + expected_array_size) << " is SPECIAL because the sum is " << expected_array_size << " the same size of the array" << std::endl;
            }

            sums.at(j) -= sums.at(i);
        }
    }

    return n_special_arrays;
}

void fillWithRandomValues(std::vector<int>& v, int min_rand=0, int max_rand=9) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {min_rand, max_rand};
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&dist](){
        return dist(randomEngine);
    });
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> elements = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::cout << mySolution(elements) << std::endl;
    return 0;
    //std::vector<int> elements(std::pow(10, 5));

//  int sol_a, sol_b;
//  int N_TESTS = 1000;
//  for (int i = 0; i < N_TESTS; ++i) {
//      //elements.clear();
//      fillWithRandomValues(elements);
//      auto start_a = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
//      sol_a = mySolution(elements);
//      auto end_a = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
//      auto start_b = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
//      sol_b = otherSolution(elements);
//      auto end_b = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
//      std::cout << "the solution took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_a - start_a).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
//      //std::cout << "the other solution took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_b - start_b).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
//
//      if (sol_a != sol_b) {
//          std::cerr << "Solutions differ for input " << vector2String(elements) << std::endl;
//          std::cerr << sol_a << " vs. " << sol_b << std::endl;
//          break;
//      }
//  }
}
```

Como observas, no se hace uso de una matriz como tal en el código. Sin embargo, lo que se computa internamente vienen siendo las filas de la matriz realmente.

La complejidad del código es `O(n^2)` pues se hacen `n`, luego `n-1`, luego `n-2`, `n-3`, `n-4`, ... hasta llegar a `0` iteraciones, y por Gauss, la complejidad termina siendo cuadrática.

La complejidad espacial es `O(n)` pues nada más requerimos una arreglo de tamaño `n` para ahí meter las filas de la matriz e irlas actualizando.

Por cierto, al final del código como comentarios agregué un test de stress. Siempre es bueno estresar al programa y verificar que se comporte adecuadamente. Por lo regular se compara una solución que dé resultados correctos con una que no estás seguro de si dará resultados correctos o no. En este caso no supe qué otra poner, así que por eso lo comenté.

Sin embargo, estuve probando algunos casos y parece que todo va bien, pero no está de más hacer más testing.

Nota: Quizá la complejidad se reduzca si los elementos están ordenados, pero precisamente desordenaría el arreglo original y daría respuestas erróneas, por eso ni lo intenté.

Nota 2: No estoy seguro de que sea la solución más óptima, pues prácticamente lo que hace es probar las combinaciones a ver cuál cumple la condición dada, pero no se me ocurrió la verdad otra forma de hacerlo. Supongo (no sé) que es necesario computar las combinaciones o de otra forma no sabremos cuál si o cuál no, no tenemos una heurística que nos diga "solo trabaja en la mitad del arreglo" (como si estuviera ordenado) para hacerlo más rápido. Quizá una mejor solución sea precisamente ordenar el arreglo y mantener aparte los índices del arreglo original para trabajar sobre el arreglo ordenado, pero modificar el arreglo original. Aunque eso ya es demasiado a mi parecer.